# Magento 1.9 observer on only new product added ( no updated product )

Tags: magento-1.9, module, event-observer

I need an observer when a new product is added, I don't need one when a product already exists and it is updated.
I found `catalog_product_save_after` and `_before` but this is triggered when a product is saved.
Is there a way to get Magento knows when a product is new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have never done this, but you can try using `catalog_product_save_before` then checking `$product->isObjectNew()` to check if the product is newly added product

Comment: Thanks it works, alternative way is checking if  product->getId() is empty.

Comment: isObjectNew() calls product->getId() internally, but it add some extra checks.